# Create tests for parser combinators in Scala

Tags: scala, testing, parser-combinators

Consider [this](https://github.com/wonook/2015_Fall_FoundationsOfSoftware/blob/master/1-arithmetic/src/main/scala/fos/Arithmetic.scala) source code that implements a parser for a term language in Scala. The main function, designed to test its functionality is defined asÑ

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val stdin = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in))
    val tokens = new lexical.Scanner(stdin.readLine())
    phrase(term)(tokens) match {
      case Success(trees, _) =>
        for (t <- path(trees))
          println(t)
        try {
          print("Big step: ")
          println(eval(trees))
        } catch {
          case TermIsStuck(t) => println("Stuck term: " + t)
        }
      case e =>
        println(e)
    }
  }
```

However, I want to test part of the functionality by calling the `term` parser on concrete input. How can I provide this input? Passing a string does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `stdin.readLine()` with your desired input, so

```
phrase(term)(new lexical.Scanner("the string you want to test")) match {
  case Success(trees, _) => ...
  case err => ...
}
```